# How to prevent duplicates in Search Results (ASP.NET Razor Syntax)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm creating a search algorithm based on keywords and sometimes phrases. I want to output results based on each word of every phrase in the search bar.

Below is my code which works fine:

```
var searchWords = Request["searchTerm"].Split(' ');
IEnumerable<dynamic> stories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
 
var sqlSelect = "SELECT TOP 10 Feeds.* FROM Feeds WHERE Feeds.AdminPublish=@1 AND Title LIKE @0 ORDER BY UploadDate DESC";
 
foreach(var word in searchWords)
{
stories = stories.Concat(db.Query(sqlSelect, "%" + word + "%",).ToList());
}
```

**In my View -Page (Result Page)**

```
@foreach (var d in stories){

//Show Title and description
@d.Title
@d.Username

}
```

Problem

Let's say am searching for "xmas of Annoying", and after searching the db, it splits the phrase into three and returns results based on LIKENESS/SIMILARITIES of the three found words. I get aresults like

The Sociology of Annoying **Xmas** Songs

Welcome to the future

The Sociology **of** Annoying Xmas Songs

Welcome to the future

The Sociology of **Annoying** Xmas Songs

Welcome to the future

How do I condition my result to not show show results that have similar ID's or how do I remove excess duplicates

Comment: you should add where clause to check if in the list exist object with the same ID.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too @Hendry

Comment: what if, instead of concat, try to check if value exist already before adding to stories?

Comment: @mybirthname I've tried adding That, can you help in constructing the appropriate WHERE clause... I can build on that

Comment: You can check the edit of ganesh, it is not efficient but probably it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use `Distinct` Keyword To Select `Distinct` from Table

```
var sqlSelect = @"SELECT distinct TOP 10 Feeds.* 
 FROM Feeds WHERE Feeds.AdminPublish=@1 AND 
 Title LIKE @0 ORDER BY UploadDate DESC";
```

**EDIT:**

then You can do like this

```
foreach(var word in searchWords)
{
stories = stories.Concat(db.Query(sqlSelect, "%" + word + "%",).ToList());
}

stories= stories.Distinct<dynamic>();
```

Comment: This will not work ! Look his code, he is spliting the searching words and have 3 lists, which he concats.

Comment: I threw in a Split, so it searches the db for words in that array, whihc definitely returns a result.. But most times these results have the same RowID... This is what am trying to condition and eliminate.. Distinct won't work. Sorry, but Thanks anyways

Comment: there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the Distinct extension method in lambda expression to achive the same in your View (Razor)

```
 @foreach (var d in stories.Distinct()){

//Show Title and description
@d.Title
@d.Username

}
```

You can also provide a specific property on the basis of which the list can be made distinct, like:

```
stories.Distinct(x=>x.Title)
//Or
stories.Distinct(x=>x.UserName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say to not add duplicate values to `stories` in the first place...

Something similar to this:

```
foreach(var word in searchWords)
{
    lst = db.Query(sqlSelect, "%" + word + "%",).ToList()
    foreach(var v in lst)
    {
        if (!stories.Contains(v))
            stories.Add(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work, How do I effect it in my View-Page.. Note: I use a foreach(var d in stories){ @d.UserName @d.Title} this might throw in a  'string' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Error

Answer (score 0):

Mike from @Mikesdotnetting.com came up with a dynamic solution, most credit goes to him, and some to me for spotting out ways to tweek the structure, for future reference; heres the solution

```
 var searchWords = Request["searchTerm"].Split(' ').Select(s => "%" + s + "%");
var sql = "SELECT TOP 10 Feeds.* FROM Feeds WHERE";
for(var i = 0; i < searchWords.Count(); i++)
{
    sql += i == 0 ? "" : " OR ";
    sql += " Title LIKE @" + i;
}
sql += " ORDER BY UploadDate DESC";
var stories = db.Query(sql, searchWords.array());
```

IF you want a result that might look something like this:

SearchTerm = "one two three"
SQL = ... where title like '%one%' or title like  '%two%'  or title like '%three%' or fname like  '%one%' or fname like  '%two%' or fname like  '%three%'  WHERE A FINAL CONDITION BINDS THEM ALL etc

If so, try this:

```
 var fields = new List<string>{"Title", "SubTitle", "Fname", "UserName", "Link"}; 
    var searchWords = Request["searchTerm"].Split(' ').Select(s => "%" + s + "%").ToList();
    var sql = "SELECT TOP 10 Feeds.* FROM Feeds WHERE (";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var i = 0;
    foreach(var word in searchWords)
    {
        foreach(var field in fields)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(" OR {0} LIKE @{1}", field, i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    sql = sql + sb.ToString().Trim().TrimStart("OR".ToCharArray()) + string.Format(") AND Feeds.AdminPublish=@{0} ORDER BY UploadDate DESC", i);
    searchWords.Add(your_parameter_value_for_AdminPublish);
    var stories = db.Query(sql, searchWords.ToArray());
```